# jquery show loading image until click function has fired/executed inner functions

Tags: jquery, ajax, function, click, return

There is this click function for an item list view switch:

```
    $("#gal").click(function() {
        $("#gal").addClass("active");
        $("#list").removeClass("active");
        $("#mos").removeClass("active");
        $(".item_page_item").hide(0, function() {
            $(".item_page_itemlist").hide();
            $.cookie("theView", "g", { expires: 7, path: "/" });
            $(this).removeClass("mos");
            $(this).addClass("gal").show();
            $(".row").each(function() {
                $(".gal",this).eq(2).addClass("third");
                $(".gal",this).eq(1).addClass("snd");
            });
        });
        return false;
    });
```

On click, you can switch between list view, galery view and grid view. Sometimes, if you have plenty of items, it need 1-2 seconds until the view has switched.

Is there a way to show a loader or anything else until the view has changed?

Comment: You can add a loader, show it before you do the `$(".item_page_item").hide()` and `hide` the loader at the end of your `$(".item_page_item").hide()` callback function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not doing anything asynchronous, so why you are using callbacks is beyond me, and since each method waits for the next method to finish, javascript being single threaded and all, you can just do :

```
$("#gal").on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#loader').show();

    $("#gal").addClass("active");
    $("#list, #mos").removeClass("active");
    $(".item_page_item, .item_page_itemlist").hide();
    $.cookie("theView", "g", { expires: 7, path: "/" });
    $(this).removeClass("mos").addClass("gal").show();
    $(".row").each(function () {
        $(".gal", this).eq(2).addClass("third").end().eq(1).addClass("snd");
    });

    $('#loader').hide();
});
```

Comment: Hehe.. exactly what I said ;-).